# ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: []

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tf.keras, image-classification, vgg-net

[image: Screenshot of the code in spyder]Hi i'm working on Image classification using XGBoost and VGG16 imagenet as feature extractor here's my code

I tried to implement feature extractor on image dataset from kaggle CK+48 with tensorflow 2.11.0. I'm facing this error,
`ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: []`
have tried alot to solve it, will appreciate the help

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import cv2
import keras
from tensorflow.keras import Model
#from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Activatation
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
import os
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, BatchNormalization
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
#from keras.optimizers import adam
import seaborn as sns
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

# Read input images and assign labels based on folder names
print(os.listdir("C:/Users/Tanzeel ur Rehman/Desktop/CK+48"))

SIZE = 256  #Resize 

#Capture training data and labels into respective lists
train_images = []
train_labels = [] 


for directory_path in glob.glob("C:/Users/Tanzeel ur Rehman/Desktop/CK+48/train"):
    label = directory_path.split("\\")[-1]
    print(label)
    for img_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*.jpg")):
        print(img_path)
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)       
        img = cv2.resize(img, (SIZE, SIZE))
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        train_images.append(img)
        train_labels.append(label)

#Convert lists to arrays        
train_images = np.array(train_images)
train_labels = np.array(train_labels)



# Capture test/validation data and labels into respective lists

test_images = []
test_labels = [] 
for directory_path in glob.glob("C:/Users/Tanzeel ur Rehman/Desktop/CK+48/test"):
    fruit_label = directory_path.split("\\")[-1]
    for img_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*.jpg")):
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (SIZE, SIZE))
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        test_images.append(img)
        test_labels.append(fruit_label)


#Convert lists to arrays                
test_images = np.array(test_images)
test_labels = np.array(test_labels)

#Encode labels from text to integers.
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(test_labels)
test_labels_encoded = le.transform(test_labels)
le.fit(train_labels)
train_labels_encoded = le.transform(train_labels)



#Split data into test and train datasets (already split but assigning to meaningful convention)
x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = train_images, train_labels_encoded, test_images, test_labels_encoded


###################################################################
# Normalize pixel values to between 0 and 1
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

#One hot encode y values for neural network. 
#from keras.utils import to_categorical
#y_train_one_hot = to_categorical(y_train)
#y_test_one_hot = to_categorical(y_test)

#############################
#Load model wothout classifier/fully connected layers
VGG_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(SIZE, SIZE, 3))

#Make loaded layers as non-trainable. This is important as we want to work with pre-trained weights
for layer in VGG_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True
    
VGG_model.summary()  #Trainable parameters will be 0


#Now, let us use features from convolutional network for RF
feature_extractor=VGG_model.predict(x_train)
```

The error is in the last line of the code, when I try to use features from convolutional network for random Forests on training dataset of images.

Comment: model.compile does not take training data, so of course it does not work.

Comment: Then what else should I pass in it?

Comment: Check the documentation: https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/

Comment: When I read model.fit() method, it have the parameters liek x,y for input or tensors... what am i missing?

Comment: I don't know, what exactly are you trying to achieve with compile/fit?

Comment: What you probably want is model.predict, not fit or compile.

Comment: and model.predict() has x in it's parameters , please check 
[link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.10.0/keras/engine/training.py#L2076) 
"""Generates output predictions for the input samples.
        Computation is done in batches. This method is designed for batch
        processing of large numbers of inputs. It is not intended for use inside
        of loops that iterate over your data and process small numbers of inputs
        at a time.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to say, explain clearly, and still you did not answer my first question (what trying to achieve exactly).

Comment: what I'm trying to acheive through model.predict() is to load the VGG model without classifiers/fully connected layers, and want to use feature extractor for Random forest as in code line `feature_extractor=VGG_model.predict(x_train)`
I hope i've explained better this time, 
I read the documentation thanks to you, and find out that model.predict() method has option to use 'x' parameter for small number of inputs

Comment: Then model.predict is what you need, no idea what you are talking about small number of inputs.

Comment: model.predict is what I need, but why am I getting error.? any hint on that?

Comment: What error are you talking about?

Comment: ValueError: could not interpret optimizer identifier :[]

Comment: I already answered that, your call to model.compile with x_train makes no sense, it is incorrect.